# Optimizing set of equations with Levenberg-Marquardt algorithm in Python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, levenberg-marquardt

I wish to use the `scipy.optimize.leastsq()` method from scipy to optimize three parameters `a,b,c`. What I do have are these two equations.

```
1*a+2*b+3*c = x1
4*a+5*b+6*c = x2
```

Analytically this set of equations is underdetermined, but numerically I am trying to find `a,b,c` to minimize the error to given results from a measurement `[2,2]`:

```
1*a+2*b+3*c - 2 = 0
4*a+5*b+6*c - 2 = 0
```

Therefore I have written some code.

```
def function(a,b,c,t):
    return np.array([1*a+2*b+3*c+t[1],4*a+5*b+6*c+t[1]])

a0 = 1
b0 = 1
c0 = 1
measdata = np.array([2,2])
t = [1,2]

def residual(x0,measdata,t):
    return measdata - function(x0[0],x0[1],x0[2],t)

erg = optimize.leastsq(func=residual,x0=(a0,b0,c0),args=(measdata,t))
```

It always results in:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-296-ab0fc90a2253> in <module>()
     14     return result - function(x0[0],x0[1],x0[2],t)
     15 
---> 16 erg = optimize.leastsq(func = residual, x0 = (a0,b0,c0) , args=(result,t), maxfev=10000)
     17 
     18 function(erg[0][0],erg[0][1])

    //anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scipy/optimize/minpack.py in leastsq(func, x0, args, Dfun, full_output, col_deriv, ftol, xtol, gtol, maxfev, epsfcn, factor, diag)
        378     m = shape[0]
        379     if n > m:
    --> 380         raise TypeError('Improper input: N=%s must not exceed M=%s' % (n, m))
        381     if epsfcn is None:
        382         epsfcn = finfo(dtype).eps
    TypeError: Improper input: N=3 must not exceed M=2
```

How do I get it to find a minimum? I am aware it's only a local minimum, but I would be happy with it.

Comment: please add the full error traceback, not just the last line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is telling you what you already know, i.e., the system is underdetermined, with `n` being the number of parameters and `m` the number of constraints.

If you fix one of the parameters so that `n > m` is `False`, the code will stop complaining. For example, change

```
def residual(x0,measdata,t):
    return measdata - function(x0[0],x0[1],x0[2],t)

erg = optimize.leastsq(func=residual,x0=(a0,b0,c0),args=(measdata,t))
```

to

```
def residual(x0,measdata,t):
    # we fix the value of `c` here
    return measdata - function(x0[0],x0[1],5,t)

# only two parameters for `x0`
erg = optimize.leastsq(func=residual,x0=(a0,b0),args=(measdata,t))
```

To answer the question how you can do what you want, I'm not sure it can be done with scipy. I found this [issue](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/1979) saying that scipy can't handle underdetermined systems:

> Interesting, I assumed the MINPACK routines would handle also m < n, but apparently not. The reason why they don't is probably that for m < n the minimum is some manifold of points, which causes problems in the termination conditions.
>
> So would be after all some interest in adding also a small-scale solver for underdetermined least-square problems.

Even though that post was from 3 years ago, I still can't find any evidence in the docs that scipy can do what you want. However, I found a SO answer that claims [you can solve for an underdetermined matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33620007/2243104), but I haven't fully grasped the mathematics yet to make sure whether it'd be applicable for your case. Since I find it hard to summarise the post, I'll just quote what seems to be the most important section.

> In the case where ***A·x*** = **b** is underdetermined,
>
> ```
> x1, res, rnk, s = np.linalg.lstsq(A, b)
> ```
>
> will pick a solution ***x'*** that minimizes *||**x**||<sub>L2</sub>*
>   subject to *||**A·x** - **b**||<sub>L2</sub> = **0***. This happens
>   not to be the particular solution we are looking for, but we can
>   linearly transform it to get what we want. In order to do that, we'll
>   first compute the [right null space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(linear_algebra)#The_row_space_of_a_matrix) of ***A***, which
>   characterizes the space of all possible solutions to ***A·x*** =
>   **b**. We can get this using a [rank-revealing QR decomposition](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.qr.html)

Comment: Thank you very much, that helped a ton!