# Matlab backslash (mldivide) versus numpy lstsq with rectangular matrix

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, scipy

I am trying to replicate an analysis in Python that we normally do with Matlab. A certain step involves solving a least squares problem with 2 rectangular matrices using the backslash \ (mldivide) operator (to solve for x in Ax = b).

I've noticed that under some circumstances, Matlab produces very different results than `np.linalg.lstsq`. If my matrix `A` is rank deficient, then `A\b` gives me a warning, but also gives me an answer with some of the columns set to all zeros.

```
A = reshape(1:35,5,7);
b = [0.5, 0.4, 0.3, 0.2, 0.1]'

A\b
Warning: Rank deficient, rank = 2, tol =  1.147983e-13. 

ans =

    -0.1200
     0
     0
     0
     0
     0
     0.0200
```

After much digging, I learned that the backslash operator does very different things depending on the input `A`. I found an excellent description here: [How to implement Matlab's mldivide (a.k.a. the backslash operator "\")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18553210/how-to-implement-matlabs-mldivide-a-k-a-the-backslash-operator). I also found a similar question to my own, but with square matrices: [Numpy vs mldivide,"\" matlab operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33559946/numpy-vs-mldivide-matlab-operator) . My situation involves rectangular matrices so it's a bit different.

When A is rectangular, `\` uses QR factorization, and I can reproduce the same solution like this:

```
[Q,R]  = qr(A);
R \ (Q'*b)
ans =

    -0.1200
     0
     0
     0
     0
     0
     0.0200
```

I understand that this second time `\` is called (for `R\(Q'*b)`) it uses back-substitution to do this. Could someone provide either Matlab or python code to do this step? I have found some examples of back-substitution, but they seem to all be for square matrices.

I realize my arbitrary example is not very realistic, and the rank deficiency is a problem, but my priority is to replicate the matlab code as closely as possible, to confirm that the other steps in the analysis are being properly replicated.

A secondary question is, is there a reason the trust the answer given by `mldivide` over `lstsq`? I understand that `lstsq` gives the minimum 2-norm solution, which seems appropriate, so how is this qualitatively different from what Matlab provides?

Comment: Related, [Numpy vs mldivide,“\” matlab operator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33559946). The matrix R in QR decomposition is trapezoid-shaped (would be trianglular if it were square). A linear system with such a matrix is solved by back-substitution, beginning with an equation that has just one unknown on the left. Being rank-deficient forces some arbitrary choices: one sets some "unneeded" variables to zero, obtaining a triangular matrix. E.g.,  when solving x+y=1, Matlab will return either [1;0] or [0;1],

Comment: I believe you have an XY problem, you really want to solve X but you're asking about Y which you cooked up while trying to solve that. Note that you can just call `lin.lstsq(A,b)` for the same result. But what's important, is a conceptual problem here. What I would've answered has already been said by @Bookend in the linked duplicate, and the comments on the corresponding question.

Comment: This makes sense. I have edited the question to focus on the issue of computing `R\(Q'*b)` using back-substitution, which was not answered in the other post. Thanks!