# Array division comparison between Matlab and Julia

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, julia

I noticed that array division gives different results in Matlab and Julia.

Matlab:

```
>[1 2 2]\[2 2 2]

ans =

 0     0     0
 1     1     1
 0     0     0
```

Julia:

```
>[1 2 2]\[2 2 2]
3×3 Array{Float64,2}:
 0.222222  0.222222  0.222222
 0.444444  0.444444  0.444444
 0.444444  0.444444  0.444444
```

They must be using different least-squares algorithms. From the documentation, though, it seems that both procedures use QR decomposition. Why do they give different outputs?

Matlab: (from 'help \')

> If A is an M-by-N matrix with M < or > N and B is a column
>       vector with M components, or a matrix with several such columns,
>       then X = A\B is the solution in the least squares sense to the
>       under- or overdetermined system of equations A*X = B. The
>       effective rank, K, of A is determined from the QR decomposition
>       with pivoting. A solution X is computed which has at most K
>       nonzero components per column. If K < N this will usually not
>       be the same solution as PINV(A)*B.  A\EYE(SIZE(A)) produces a
>       generalized inverse of A.

Julia (from '? \')

> \ (A, B)
>
> Matrix division using a polyalgorithm. For input matrices A and B, the result X is such that A*X == B when A is square. The solver that is used depends upon the structure of A. If A is upper or lower triangular (or diagonal), no factorization of A is required and the system is solved with either forward or backward substitution. For non-triangular square matrices, an LU factorization is used.
>
> For rectangular A the result is the minimum-norm least squares solution computed by a pivoted QR factorization of A and a rank estimate of A based on the R factor.
>
> When A is sparse, a similar polyalgorithm is used. For indefinite matrices, the LDLt factorization does not use pivoting during the numerical factorization and therefore the procedure can fail even for invertible matrices.

Comment: Explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33559946/numpy-vs-mldivide-matlab-operator

Comment: I’ve marked it as duplicate because Julia obviously behaves like NumPy there, and so the dupe answer answers this question also, even if the questions are not identical.