# how to manipulate a variable that store multiple numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I am new to python and I want to implement the algorithm in matlab using python as i found the solution from here: [Numpy vs mldivide,"\" matlab operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33559946/numpy-vs-mldivide-matlab-operator)

When I print the shape of the sol variable I got:

(3, 1)
(3, 1)
(3, 1)

Here is the answer of sol variable:

```
[[-1. ]
 [ 4.5]
 [ 0. ]]

[[ 8.]
 [ 0.]
 [ 6.]]

[[ 0.        ]
 [ 4.        ]
 [ 0.66666667]]
```

My desire answer:

```
[[ 0.        ]
 [ 4.        ]
 [ 0.66666667]]
```

How can I select the last numpy-array as it is the solution I need as it is the solution of matlab. Thanks before hand!

Comment: "When I print the shape of the sol variable I got:

(3, 1) (3, 1) (3, 1)" No, you don't. Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty straightforward as follows:

```
>>> arr = np.arange(9).reshape(3,3)
>>> arr
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5],
       [6, 7, 8]])
>>> arr[2::]
array([[6, 7, 8]])
```

OR

```
>>> arr[-1::]
array([[6, 7, 8]])
```